# What if I don't upgrade from 11.04

Tags: 11.04, upgrade

My friend asked me this question. I tell him about old program's and security problem's. Is there any more possible problems?

Answer (score 2):

When a release stops being supported (as Natty Narwhal (11.04) was in October of last year) three things happen:

1. The repositories get moved making it much more difficult to install new software.
2. All development stops so there will be no bug fixes and security patches.
3. Support on sites such as this one and [Launchpad](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+questions) stops

I would definitely recommend only using supported versions of any OS.

If you have older hardware then consider a lighter desktop such as [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/getxubuntu/) or [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/) both are supported here and will run on lower specification machines.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not, I think a good reason to keep "old" version is the age of the PC and it's configuration: hardware, video cards, memory, etc.

On the contrary, if you will latest software release whether for reasons of safety or not then update your system.

Finally, in your case, I think the use of a LTS release might be a good alternative